# How to fix scrapy returns item in scrapy shell but not in spider code

Tags: python, scrapy

I tested and tried the selectors in the scrapy shell and they all work. When I use only the players urls aline it works. But it returns `None` when the spider is crawled from the code and I fetch the players' urls this way.

```
class TransfersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "transfers"
    start_urls = []
    for year in range(1970, 2022)[29:31]:  # for each transfer year
            url = f"https://www.transfermarkt.com/transfers/saisontransfers/statistik/top/ajax/yw0/saison_id/{year}/transferfenster/alle/land_id//ausrichtung//spielerposition_id//altersklasse//leihe//plus/0/galerie/0/"
            start_urls.append(url)   

    def parse(self, response):    
        for page_num in range(1,2):
            page_url = response.url + f"page/{page_num}?/ajax=yw0"
            yield scrapy.Request(page_url, callback=self.parse_page)
                
    def parse_page(self,response):
        players_urls_ =  response.css('table[class="items"] > tbody > tr > td>table>tr>td').css('a[href*=profil]::attr(href)').getall()[0:1]
        players_urls = ["https://www.transfermarkt.com"+url for url in players_urls_]

        for player_url in players_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(player_url, callback=self.parse_info)
            
    def parse_info(self, response):
        item = dict()       
        info_table = response.css('div[class="large-6 large-pull-6 small-12 columns spielerdatenundfakten"]')
        name = response.xpath('//h1//text()').getall()
        name = ' '.join([i.strip() for i in name if (i.strip() and i.strip().isalpha())])      
        item["name"] = name     
        item["date_of_birth"] =  info_table.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Date of birth:")]/following-sibling::span/a/text()').get(default="").strip()      
        item["place_of_birth"] = info_table.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Place of birth:")]/following-sibling::span/span/text()').get(default="").strip()       
        item["height"] = info_table.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Height:")]/following-sibling::span/text()').get(default="").strip()     
        item["citizenship"] =  info_table.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Citizenship:")]/following-sibling::span/img/@title').get().strip()               
        item["foot"] = info_table.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Foot:")]/following-sibling::span/text()').get(default="").strip()        
        player_agent =  info_table.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Player agent:")]/following-sibling::span/span/text()').get(default="").strip() #player agent has two possible xpaths
        item["player_agent"] = info_table.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Player agent:")]/following-sibling::span/span/a/text()').get(default="").strip() or player_agent   
        item["main_position"] = response.css('div[class="detail-position__inner-box"] > dl> dd::text').get(default="").strip()
        item["other_position"] = response.css('div[class="detail-position__position"] > dl>  dd::text').getall() or ["none"]        
        item["outfitter"] = info_table.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Outfitter:")]/following-sibling::span/text()').get(default="").strip()        
        
        yield item
```

OUTPUT with regular spider:

```
2022-09-29 19:15:44 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.transfermarkt.com/christian-vieri/profil/spieler/5797>
{'citizenship': '',
 'date_of_birth': '',
 'foot': '',
 'height': '',
 'main_position': 'Centre-Forward',
 'name': 'Christian Vieri',
 'other_position': ['none'],
 'outfitter': '',
 'place_of_birth': '',
 'player_agent': ''}
2022-09-29 19:15:44 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.transfermarkt.com/luis-figo/profil/spieler/3446>
{'citizenship': '',
 'date_of_birth': '',
 'foot': '',
 'height': '',
 'main_position': 'Right Winger',
 'name': 'Luís Figo',
 'other_position': ['none'],
 'outfitter': '',
 'place_of_birth': '',
 'player_agent': ''}
```

OUTPUT when I used only the players' urls:

```
2022-09-29 19:12:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.transfermarkt.com/christian-vieri/profil/spieler/5797> (referer: None)
2022-09-29 19:12:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.transfermarkt.com/christian-vieri/profil/spieler/5797>
{'name': 'Christian Vieri', 'date_of_birth': 'Jul 12, 1973', 'place_of_birth': 'Bologna', 'height': '1,85\xa0m', 'citizenship': 'Italy', 'foot': 'left', 'player_agent': '', 'main_position': '', 'other_position': ['none'], 'outfitter': ''}
2022-09-29 19:12:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.transfermarkt.com/luis-figo/profil/spieler/3446> (referer: None)
2022-09-29 19:12:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.transfermarkt.com/luis-figo/profil/spieler/3446>
{'name': 'Luís Figo', 'date_of_birth': 'Nov 4, 1972', 'place_of_birth': 'Almada', 'height': '1,80\xa0m', 'citizenship': 'Portugal', 'foot': 'right', 'player_agent': '', 'main_position': 'Right Winger', 'other_position': ['Right Midfield', 'Attacking Midfield'], 'outfitter': ''}
```

Why are the selectors working with in the scrapy shell or when scraped with only the players' urls, but not in the scrapy spider? And why does only the name and main_position selectors work and others not?

Answer (score 1):

I tried diagnosing the response from the function `parse_info`, and just added this before the parsing:

```
def parse_info(self, response):
    from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
    inspect_response(response, self)
```

This opened a scrapy shell which enable me to view the response the way scrapy sees it and to test the selectors. Apparently the selectors were not the same from the website as the one scarpy is seeing. The info_table selector should be changed to `response.css('div[class="large-12 small-12 columns spielerdatenundfakten"]')` and it'll work.